# function Search using textbox and flexgrid with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new in MVVM and i need some help in my project. So I need to implement a function search which I write the name in the text box and it shows the result in the flexgrid with MVVM and C#

Answer (score 0):

you should use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) for connection 
and [Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for your data

Comment: Thank you  but I my application is desktop

Comment: you can still use this lib's